# Pandas - count if multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Having a dataframe in python:

```
CASE    TYPE
1          A
1          A
1          A
2          A
2          B
3          B
3          B
3          B
```

how can I create a result dataframe which would yield all cases and either an "A" if the case had only "A's" assigned, "B" if it was only "B's" or "MIXED" if the case had both A and B?

Result would be then:

```
Case     Type
1        A
2        MIXED
3        B
```

Comment: What have you tired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option, where we firstly collect the TYPE as list by group of `CASE` and then check the `length` of unique TYPE, if it is larger than `1`, return `MIXED` otherwise the TYPE by itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
groups = df.groupby('CASE').agg(lambda g: [g.TYPE.unique()]).
            apply(lambda row: np.where(len(row.TYPE) > 1, 'MIXED', row.TYPE[0]), axis = 1)
groups

# CASE
# 1           A
# 2       MIXED
# 3           B
# dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['NTYPES'] = df.groupby('CASE').transform(lambda x: x.nunique())
df.loc[df.NTYPES > 1, 'TYPE'] = 'MIXED'
df.groupby('TYPE', as_index=False).first().drop('NTYPES', 1)

    TYPE  CASE
0      A     1
1      B     3
2  MIXED     2
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one bit ugly, but not that slow solution:

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]:
    CASE TYPE
0      1    A
1      1    A
2      1    A
3      2    A
4      2    B
5      3    B
6      3    B
7      3    B
8      4    C
9      4    C
10     4    B

In [155]: %paste
(df.groupby('CASE')['TYPE']
   .apply(lambda x: x.head(1) if x.nunique() == 1 else pd.Series(['MIX']))
   .reset_index()
   .drop('level_1', 1)
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[155]:
   CASE TYPE
0     1    A
1     2  MIX
2     3    B
3     4  MIX
```

**Timing:** against 800K rows DF:

```
In [191]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [192]: df.shape
Out[192]: (800000, 3)

In [193]: %timeit Psidom(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 235 ms per loop

In [194]: %timeit capitalistpug(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 419 ms per loop

In [195]: %timeit Alberto_Garcia_Raboso(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop

In [196]: %timeit MaxU(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 80.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (admittedly over-engineered) solution that avoids looping over groups and `DataFrame.apply` (these are slow, so avoiding them may become important if your dataset gets sufficiently large).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CASE': [1]*3 + [2]*2 + [3]*3,
                   'TYPE': ['A']*4 + ['B']*4})
```

We group by `CASE` and compute the relative frequencies of `TYPE` being `A` or `B`:

```
grouped = df.groupby('CASE')
vc = (grouped['TYPE'].value_counts(normalize=True)
                     .unstack(level=0)
                     .fillna(0))
```

Here's what `vc` looks like

```
CASE   1    2    3
TYPE
A      1.0  0.5  0.0
B      0.0  0.5  0.0
```

Notice that all the information is contained in the first row. Cutting said row into bins with `pd.cut` gives the desired result:

```
tolerance = 1e-10
bins = [-tolerance, tolerance, 1-tolerance, 1+tolerance]
types = pd.cut(vc.loc['A'], bins=bins, labels=['B', 'MIXED', 'A'])
```

We get:

```
CASE
1        A
2    MIXED
3        B
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [B < MIXED < A]
```

For good measure, we can rename the `types` series:

```
types.name = 'TYPE'
```